# What is "señor de los avioncitos"?

Tags: traducción, coloquialismos

I've looked everywhere and I can't find what it means. The context is someone is looking for a car in a car park and says:

> ¿Ahí, no es el que está al lado del señor de los avioncitos?

It's driving me insane!

Comment: Welcome to [Spanish.SE]! We'll try to answer your question, but we may need more information. Could you please tell us the country in which you heard that? For now, I can tell you that an "avioncito" is just a little "avión".

Comment: It looks like they are pointing something that is just next to a guy with some little planes (maybe in a park where someone is playing with some drones?)

Comment: Looks like it was taken from [this article](http://www.revistaohlala.com/1439949-vacaciones-sonadas) published in an Argentine magazine. If so, it most probably refers to someone who sells airplane-shaped kites, which are commonly sold at Argentine beaches (such as the one where the events in the article take place).

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I'm in the UK and it's part of a translation, I think the kite guy makes sense when I read the rest of it. Muchísima gracias

Answer (score 5):

Looks like it was taken from the article [¿Vacaciones soñadas?: cuando la playa es una pesadilla](http://www.revistaohlala.com/1439949-vacaciones-sonadas), published in a women's magazine from Argentina. If so, it most probably refers to someone who sells airplane-shaped kites, which are commonly sold at Argentine beaches (such as the one where the events in the article take place).